# List of Lists: Comparing indexes of all lists inside a master list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists of integers.
Such as

```
RedValues=[R,R1,R2,R3,R4]
```

R through R4 are all lists of integers.

What I need to do is compare the first value in each sublist and "take" the median value.

Specifically I am rebuilding an image with 9 different images and taking the median red color pixel in each file.

If anyone can be of assistance with this particular problem I appreciate it.

So `R[3]` compared to `R1[3]` compared to `R2[3]`...and take median.

Thinking about a nested for loop?...
for x in RedValues:
    for x in R:
        ...?

Comment: Why isn't your code working?  Please post it.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over all the 0th elements, then the 1st, then the 2nd... using `zip`:

```
for rs in zip(*RedValues):
    m = median(list(rs))
```

Comment: where m is the new list of all median values?

Comment: No, it's the median of `[R[i], R1[i], R2[i], R3[i], R4[i]]`. You'll have to implement `median` yourself, or `from statistics import median` in Python 3.4 or higher.

Comment: Why turn ```rs``` into  a list?